# Python Pandas DataFrame of objects to json does not export all properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a pandas dataframe that contains Objects of Cell, this is the class:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, data, coordinates, cell_id):
        self._cell_id = cell_id
        self._coordinates = coordinates
        self._data = data

    @property
    def data(self) -> str:
        return self._data

    @property
    def coordinates(self) -> dict:
        return self._coordinates

    @property
    def cell_id(self) -> str:
        return self._cell_id

    @property
    def empty(self) -> bool:
        if self._data == 0:
            return False

        return self._data is None or self._data == ""

    def set_data(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._data
```

every item in the dataframe is represented by this class.
but when trying to transform this class to json, for some reason not all values from the class are exported to the json.

this is the command i am using:

```
json.loads(df.to_json())
```

and the results looks like this:

```
{
    "header_col1": {
        "1": {
            "cell_id": "705f7e89-abd4-4f7b-adfb-802010016546",
            "data": "7579"
        },
        "2": {
            "cell_id": "f04f3168-95d1-45f6-bb41-fc572736aeb7",
            "data": "6207"
        }
    },
    "header_col2": {
        "1": {
            "cell_id": "03fce322-a6d4-40ba-abbe-4f2558e6805f",
            "data": "some text"
        },
        "2": {
            "cell_id": "7b373ba4-e062-4881-99c6-2beaa0a20bcb",
            "data": "some text"
        },
    }
}
```

i expected it to export all other fields of the Cell object as well, i don't understand why it exports only those 2 specific fields..

to reproduce the issue you can try using this:

```
mat = []
cords = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "w": 0, "h": 0}
for i in range(5):
    row = []
    for b in range(3):
        row.append(Cell(cell_id=f"id_{b}", coordinates=cords, data=f"data_{b}"))
    mat.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(mat)
json.loads(df.to_json())
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Please detail how you build your df in the question.

Comment: @Tranbi i have edited my post and added a way to reproduce the issue

Comment: I still get the coodinates in my output using the added code `{'0': {'0': {'cell_id': 'id_0', 'coordinates': {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'w': 0, 'h': 0}, 'data': 'data_0', 'empty': False}, '1': ...` What is the issue exactly?

Comment: @Tranbi so i was running pandas 1.3 on python3.9, apparently the bug exists there, when upgrading to pandas 1.43 the problem was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem exists on pandas 1.3 on python3.9
upgrading to pandas 1.43 solves the issue